Good resources for learning about quantum batteries and quantum metrology
I am a 1st year PhD student, beginning my research on quantum information. I would like to learn about quantum metrology and quantum batteries in depth, from scratch. Can anyone suggest good books/review articles/lecture videos that cover these at an introductory level?
